# how to use a lambda expression for a validation to verify if an hour s a certain "type"(has to be hh:00 or hh:30)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

```
RuleFor(m => m.StartDate)
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage(x => Validation.EventMessages.EmptyStartDate)
    .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.UtcNow).WithMessage(x => Validation.EventMessages.StartDatePast).When(m => m.EndDate.HasValue)
    .LessThan(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1)).WithMessage(x => Validation.EventMessages.StartDateFuture).When(m => m.EndDate.HasValue)
    .LessThan(m => m.EndDate.Value).WithMessage(x => Validation.EventMessages.GreaterThan).When(m => m.EndDate.HasValue)
    .LessThan(m => DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)).WithMessage(x => Validation.EventMessages.CancellationTimeSpanLess).When(m => m.EventStatus == (int)EventStatusEnum.cancelled)
    .Must(CanBook).WithMessage(x => Validation.EventMessages.Limit);
```

I have to create an event which has StartDate, EndDate, userid etc. The StartDate is Datetime and i have to make this validation , the StartDate for the event has to be hh:00 or hh:30. 
This is what i used for all the other validations(up).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.CreatedDate)
    .Must(x => (x.Minute == 0 || x.Minute == 30) /*&& x.Second == 0*/)
    .WithMessage("Your Message here")
    //other validations
```

Comment: In the end we changed the way we approached this but this worked. I changed x.minute into x.Value.Minute. Thank you for your help